# Count the number of classes

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a filter with multiple options. As you can see, there are sometimes no results. I give this back to the visitor as user feedback by saying: no results.

Now I want to show the visitor the number of results already in the filter option. For example: Show all (10) or Education (1). This way a user knows what he can expect and don't choose for a empty filter.

But something makes it really complex: The numbers can change with certain combination. For example: if you choose filter one, there are less options for filter two. etc.

Can anyone help me?

```html
$("select.filterby").change(function() {
  var filters = $.map($("select.filterby").toArray(), function(e) {
    return $(e).val();
  }).join(".");
  $("div#FilterContainer").find("div.job-offer-card").hide();
  if ($("div#FilterContainer").find("div.job-offer-card." + filters).length) {
    $("div#FilterContainer").find("div.job-offer-card." + filters).show();

  } else {
    $("div#FilterContainer").find("div.noresults").show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span> View by:</span>


    <label for="location">Location</label>
    <select id="location" class="filterby">
       <option value="all">Show All</option>
       <option value="australia">Australia</option>
       <option value="singapore">Singapore</option>
       <option value="newzealand">New Zealand</option>
       <option value="usa">USA</option>
       <option value="uk">UK</option>
       <option value="vietnam">Vietnam</option>
       <option value="global">Global</option>
       <option value="othercountry">Other</option>
    </select>


    <label for="type">Type</label>
    <select id="type" class="filterby">
       <option value="all">Show All</option>
       <option value="accommodation">Accommodation</option>
       <option value="app">App/Technology</option>
       <option value="business">Business</option>
       <option value="health">Health</option>
       <option value="hospitality">Hospitality</option>
       <option value="education">Education</option>
       <option value="retail">Retail</option>
       <option value="services">Services</option>
       <option value="travel">Travel</option>
    </select>

    <label for="code">Code</label>
    <select id="code" class="filterby">
       <option value="all">Show All</option>
       <option value="001">001</option>
       <option value="002">002</option>
       <option value="003">003</option>
       <option value="004">004</option>
    </select>

<div id="FilterContainer">
  <div class="job-offer-card noresults">
    <p>no results</p>
  </div>
  <div class="job-offer-card all vietnam accommodation travel 004">
    <p>1 all vietnam accommodation travel</p>
  </div>
  <div class="job-offer-card all vietnam  travel 003">
    <p>2 all vietnam travel</p>
  </div>
  <div class="job-offer-card all vietnam accommodation travel">
    <p>3 all vietnam accommodation travel</p>
  </div>
  <div class="job-offer-card all australia accommodation travel 003">
    <p>4 all australia accommodation travel</p>
  </div>
  <div class="job-offer-card all australia education">
    <p>5 all australia</p>
  </div>
  <div class="job-offer-card all vietnam newzealand usa accommodation">
    <p>6 all vietnam accommodation</p>
  </div>
  <div class="job-offer-card all vietnam accommodation travel">
    <p>7 all vietnam accommodation travel</p>
  </div>
  <div class="job-offer-card all vietnam  travel">
    <p>8 all vietnam travel</p>
  </div>
  <div class="job-offer-card all vietnam accommodation travel">
    <p>9 all vietnam accommodation travel</p>
  </div>
  <div class="job-offer-card all australia accommodation travel">
    <p>10 all australia accommodation travel</p>
  </div>
  <div class="job-offer-card all australia health 001">
    <p>11 all australia</p>
  </div>
  <div class="job-offer-card all vietnam accommodation 002">
    <p>12 all vietnam accommodation</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `length` property of any jquery object will contain the number of elements. You've already used it.

If you want to add the number to each option, you can just loop through all of them and count each case.

```
$("select.filterby option").each(function() {
    var t=$(this),
        val=t.val(),
        text=t.text(),
        count=$("#FilterContainer").find("div.job-offer-card."+val).length;
    v.text(text+" ("+val+")");
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your respons! I am probably very stupid but I don't quite know where to put this part of code. Do I need to replace my code or add it? How can I get the number after the option? Do I have to use an echo for this? Thanks again

Comment: `echo`? No, this is JS code. This will loop through the _existing_ options of the `select`s and append the number to each one. Therefore it should be executed after the DOM is ready. So, place it inside a DOM ready or page load event handler. See https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/